# powershell - how to unseparate variable with commas

Tags: powershell, variables, dns

i have variable separated with commas

```
$ous = 'nameou1, nameou2, nameou3'
```

how to make organizational units with this variable so the ou can have names like the words in variable

Comment: Please take a moment and take the [Tour] and read at least the help topic [Ask]. And you may elaborate more detailed what you want to achieve. You might share an example of the expected result. Where does this variable comes from? why is it not an array? `$ous = 'nameou1', 'nameou2', 'nameou3'`

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. Although a good question, it is always a good idea to add some code, so that the community knows what your already have worked on and can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do but you could try following to get those strings as properties of an object

```
    $obj = New-Object PSObject; "nameou1, nameou2, nameou3" -split "," | 
    %{ Add-Member -InputObject $obj -NotePropertyName $_.Trim() -NotePropertyValue "" }
```

Result object;

```
nameou1 nameou2  nameou3
------- -------- --------
```

Alternatively, Hashtable is said to be faster and could be preferred with its concise syntax;

```
$obj = @{}; "nameou1, nameou2, nameou3" -split "," |  %{ $obj.add($_.Trim(), "")}
```

Comment: If you're not sure about the question you might ask in a comment and wait for clarification before taking wild guesses and running in the wrong direction. ;-) :D